# Loading node libraries in Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm, google-cloud-storage

First of all, I'm learning Web Apps by myself using Vue 2 + Firebase technology. Explanations for dummies would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to list the buckets from Cloud Storage (Google Cloud Platform) in my front-end. So I found a node [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage#samples) to do this exact task. I created a Vue component to list the buckets, but when I try to import the node library to the component (inside script tag)

```
import storage from '@google-cloud/storage'
```

I get this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                         13:34:51
 error  in ./node_modules/configstore/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|               if (defaults) {
|                       this.all = {
|                               ...defaults,
|                               ...this.all
|                       };

 @ ./node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js 19:20-42
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/components/Bucket.vue
 @ ./src/components/Bucket.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I don't even know if its possible to use this kind of library in a Vue component or I need to have a node.js back-end environment. Before continuing with the component development, I want to know if its possible to use the node library in the component because I'm pretty lost about that.

This are my dependencies versions in case need:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "firebase": "^7.8.0",
    "googleapis": "^47.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-firestore": "^0.3.30",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This package `@google-cloud/storage` is for Node.js environment and that's why it doesn't work in a browser. On `npm` repositories you will find almost anything, but you really need to know what platform is it aimed for. Reading docs usually helps understanding if you found the right package.

For this to work you would need some Node API layer where you will use `@google-cloud/storage`, and in your Vue app, you would then consume that API.

Comment: I see. I dont have the knowledge to start a node backend layer so I'll keep looking for a solution to list the buckets without that library.